# Update general setting of website using codeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

This table of  [General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIWCV.jpg)

I am a beginner in CodeIgniter so I am doing to update my general settings record into a database table for a website but on form submission is nothing going to update and show no errors. I am trying to change my update passing arguments and update query. Can somebody suggest an idea?

**Controller**

```
class Admin extends CI_Controller
 {
  public function viewSettings()
   {
    if(! $this->session->userdata('id') )
    return redirect('Admin/login');

    $this->load->model('loginmodel');
    $settings=$this->loginmodel->settingList();
    $this->load->view('general-settings',['settings'=> $settings]);
    }
 }


public function updateSettings()
{
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $site_name = $this->input->post('site_name');
    $site_url = $this->input->post('site_url');
    $address = $this->input->post('address');
    $tel_phone = $this->input->post('tel_phone');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');


    $this->load->model('loginmodel');
    if($this->loginmodel->settingUpdate($id,$site_name,$site_url,$address,$tel_phone,$email))
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'General Settings updated Successfully');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class', 'alert-success');
    }

    redirect(base_url().'Admin/viewSettings');
}
```

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url().'admin/updateSettings'?>">

                                <div class="card-body card-block">
                                    <?php foreach($settings as $setting) { 
                                        if($setting->title!='image') {
                                        ?>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="nf-firstname" class=" form-control-label"><?php echo $setting->title;?></label>
                                            <input type="text" id="nf-email" name="<?php echo $setting->key_title;?>" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $setting->value;?>">
                                            <?php echo form_error('$setting->value');?>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php } }?>
                                        <input type="hidden" name="updated_at" id="updated_at" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")?>">
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                                        <i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Submit
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                </form>
```

**Model**

```
class loginmodel extends CI_Model
{
 public function settingList()
  {
    $query = $this->db->select()
                      ->from('general_settings')
                      ->get();
                      return $query->result();
  }

public function settingUpdate($id,$site_name,$site_url,$address,$tel_phone,$email)
{
    $data = array(
    'value' => $site_name,
    'value' => $site_url,
    'value' => $address,
    'value' => $tel_phone,
    'value' => $email
    );

    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('general_settings',$data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
//controller
class Admin extends CI_Controller
 {
     public function updateSettings(){
        $post_data = $this->input->post();
        $this->load->model('loginmodel');
        if($this->loginmodel->settingUpdate($post_data))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'General Settings updated Successfully');
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg_class', 'alert-success');
        }

        redirect(base_url().'Admin/viewSettings');
    }
 }

 //modal
 class loginmodel extends CI_Model
{
         public function settingUpdate($post_data){
            foreach($post_data as $key => $value){
            $data = array('value'=>$value);
            $this->db->where('key_title', $key);
            $this->db->update('general_settings',$data);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: data is updating or not? make ENVIRONMENT = development to see error.

Comment: try to print query using echo $this->db->last_query(); to check and debug.